# Is running shifter cables over the stem a bad idea?

Tags: cable-routing

[image: picture of cockpit configuration]

I don't like how much the cables bend if I run them under the stem.

[image: finished cockpit]

In the end, I actually had them on backwards and when I swapped them I was able to get acceptable cable runs to the stops on the other side of the downtube.

Comment: Also, any other cable routing tips and tricks would be nice. I'm planning before I snip the other shifter.

Comment: I'm going with Sheldon's commandments and crossing my fingers.

Comment: Can you post pic the entire handlebar setup? why are the shifters down near the stem?

Comment: Yeah, the shifters are not very well oriented.  (But that style of shifter is pretty hard to get right no matter where you put it.)

Comment: I'd be using my favorite stem shifter levers if they fit on this stem. This was as close as I could get to that.

Comment: Have you tried putting the shifters on the ends of the bars, as they point toward the steerer?  Or possibly just inboard of the brake lever mounts?  I have a friction lever like that to control a quad, and its too far from the left-hand to change comfortably, somewhat like yours.

Comment: You can always add your answer as an answer and accept it, because that's what worked for you.  I wouldn't have picked them as being mounted backward.